# Can I call my notification function from the server when the app is closed?

Tags: cordova, notifications

i'd like to know if I can call a function in my app from the server when my app is closed ?
Like call a local notification function when my server recieves a new message.
My server is in nodejs and i'm using mongodb.
Thanks !

Comment: sure thing! you can enable background push notification handler. btw, you should care of `double call` of handler.
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#push-message-arrives-with-app-in-background

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, so I read almost all the page, but I can't manage to understand how do I send from the server to my closed app client, could you past me links/anchors to where it says so exactly please ? Because all I can see is how to initialize the notification !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Arzacks!

Now, would u let me show u some snippets of backend? (it's only a ref sample)

> This sample is using AWS SNS for push notification. **You should pay attention to JSON PAYLOADS**. Due to `content-available` param, the notification handler is registered to mobile devices as a BACKGROUND process. In the ***frontend*** logic, you should deal with `cold-start` event handler.

```
...
// compose push message
apnsJSON = {
  aps: {
    alert: 'PUSH MSG FROM APPLE',
    sound: 'default',
    'content-available': '1',
    category: 'tabs.contact_pr', // param 4 client routing
  },
  // below are my custom params, ignore them
  target: '4',
  notId: '100204',
  notWhen: fn_current_moment()
};
gcmJSON = {
  data: {
    message: 'PUSH MSG FROM FIREBASE',
    sound: 'default',
    'content-available': '1',
    'force-start': '1',
    category: 'tabs.contact_pr', // param 4 client routing
    // below are my custom params, ignore them
    target: '4',
    notId: '100204',
    notWhen: fn_current_moment()
  }
};
var payload = JSON.stringify({
  default: 'TESTING PUSH MSG',
  APNS: JSON.stringify(apnsJSON),
  APNS_SANDBOX: JSON.stringify(apnsJSON),
  GCM: JSON.stringify(gcmJSON)
});
// AWS SNS publish now
// sending push to parent...
sns.publish({
  Message: payload,
  MessageStructure: 'json',
  TopicArn: String(topic.topicARN)
}, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {}
  callback();
});
...
```

Comment: Okay thanks for this code, I kind of get it now, so sns.publish(...) is to send the notification right ? 
Is there a way I can send the notification to a user by using his token now ?